# AssertionError when executing PreparedStatement using Oracle thin JDBC

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc

I ran into a curious (what looks like a) bug with PreparedStatements using Oracle's thin JDBC driver (ojdbc7). An AssertionError occurs when executing a PreparedStatement multiple times, and seems to be related to setting null bind values.

Here's an excerpt of the test code that demonstrates this:

```
  private void insertRows(String tableName) throws SQLException
  {
    String insertSQL = 
      "INSERT INTO "
          + tableName
          + " (objectid, attributeid, sequence, value)"
          + " VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)";
    PreparedStatement stmt = m_Conn.prepareStatement(insertSQL);
    
    // insert first 3 rows with same objId and attrId
    long objId = 700;
    long attrId = 701;
    int seq = 1;

    stmt.setLong(1, objId);
    stmt.setLong(2, attrId);

    // 1st row (non-null value)
    stmt.setInt(3, seq++);
    stmt.setString(4, "Foo");
    stmt.execute();

    // 2nd row (null value)
    stmt.setInt(3, seq++);
    stmt.setNull(4, Types.VARCHAR);
    stmt.execute();

    // 3rd row (null value)
    stmt.setInt(3, seq++);
    stmt.setNull(4, Types.VARCHAR);
    stmt.execute();

    // insert next 2 rows with new objId and attrId
    objId = 800;
    attrId = 801;
    seq = 1;

    stmt.setLong(1, objId);
    stmt.setLong(2, attrId);

    // 1st row (null value)
    stmt.setInt(3, seq++);
    stmt.setNull(4, Types.VARCHAR);
    stmt.execute();

    // 2nd row (non-null value)
    stmt.setInt(3, seq++);
    stmt.setString(4, "Bar");
    stmt.execute();  // this results in an AssertionError

    System.out.println("Inserts were successful");
    stmt.close();
  }
```

The 5th execution of the PreparedStatement results in an AssertionError:

```
Expected AssertionError: java.lang.AssertionError: lastOffset: 5        leastOffset: 5  indexOfLeastOffet: 3
java.lang.AssertionError: lastOffset: 5 leastOffset: 5  indexOfLeastOffet: 3
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.compressLastBoundData(OraclePreparedStatement.java:1902)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.setupDbaBindBuffers(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3062)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.setupBindBuffers(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3046)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.processCompletedBindRow(OraclePreparedStatement.java:2670)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeInternal(OraclePreparedStatement.java:4790)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.execute(OraclePreparedStatement.java:4901)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.execute(OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.java:1385)
        at oracle.Dave.Bug912.insertRows(Bug912.java:130)
        at oracle.Dave.Bug912.main(Bug912.java:38)
```

The AssertionError only occurs with specific combinations of bind value settings, and seems to be related to the setting of null values (the error does not occur if null values are not used). It also doesn't occur with assertions disabled (obviously). The database version does not seem to matter - I have seen this against both 11.2 and 12.1.

Has anyone seen this sort of bug before? I can attach a complete test case if anyone is interested.

Comment: can you try `executeUpdate()`

Comment: Same result with executeUpdate().

Comment: Which version of Oracle (full versions please!) are you using and which version of the Oracle JDBC driver (ojdbc7 is not a version, it indicates it is for Java 7).

Comment: The driver version is: 
Oracle 12.1.0.2.0 JDBC 4.1 compiled with JDK7 on Mon_Jun_30_11:30:34_PDT_2014

Comment: The database version is 12.1.0.2.0